# WebApi documentation not recognizing endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have multiple controller endpoints with routes like this:

```
[Route("api/myobjects/action1/action2/{objectIds}")]
```

They all have method signatures like this (access modifier and return type omitted):

```
Post([ModelBinder(typeof(CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder))] int[] objectIds)
```

The custom modelbinder allows me to post to the endpoint like so:

```
../api/myobjects/action1/action2/1,2,3
```

This works great! However, all these methods are ignored by the help pages documentation generating process.

If I remove the modelbinder attribute like so:

```
Post(int[] objectIds)
```

It still does not work. Only if I add `[FromUri]` to the parameter and delete `{objectIds}` from the route attribute it will work:

```
Post([FromUri] int[] objectIds)
```

But this generates a uri that is unwanted like so:

```
../api/myobjects/action1/action2?objectIds[0]={objectIds[0]}&objectIds[1]={objectIds[1]}
```

---

How can I get the help pages documentation process to recognise my endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update HelpPageConfig like 
config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(ObjectType), "Object", "MethodName");

using this you can enable help for respective URL in web api

Comment: Sadly, this has no effect on the problem I'm experiencing. I tried both config.SetActualResponseType and config.SetActualRequestType.

Comment: if you are using web api 2, there is a nuget package u can install to show help pages, it will automatically find the end points, sorry for so delay in reply